# Calling PHP Parent Constructors With Old/New Syntax

Tags: php, oop, constructor

Given the class Foo with an old-style constructor

```
class Foo
{
    public function Foo()
    {
        //does constructing stuff
    }
}
```

Is there any functional difference between calling the parent constructor with a new style constructor or the old style constructor?

```
class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function Bar()
    {
        //does it matter?
        //parent::__construct();
        //parent::Foo();
    }
}
```

Put another way, is there anything special about the static call

```
parent::__construct()
```

when it's made from a constructor, or is it just a standard static call?

Before the Best Practices Flying Monkeys descend, I'm dealing with some legacy code and trying to understand the consequences of everything that's going on.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would say both syntax do exactly the same thing...

Edit : after writting the rest of the answer, actually, this is not entirely true ^^ It depends on what you declare ; see the two examples :

If you define `Foo` as constructor, and call it with `__construct`, it seems it's working ; the following code :

```
class Foo {
    public function Foo() {
        var_dump('blah');
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public function Bar() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

$a = new Bar();
```

Outputs

```
string 'blah' (length=4)
```

So, all OK for now ;-)

On the other way, if you define __construct, and call Foo, like this :

```
class Foo {
    public function __construct() {
        var_dump('blah');
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public function Bar() {
        parent::Foo();
    }
}

$a = new Bar();
```

It'll get you a Fatal Error :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Foo::foo()
```

So, if your class is declared with old-syntax, you can call it both ways ; and if it's defined with new (PHP5) syntax, you must use that new syntax -- which makes sense, afterall :-)

BTW, if you want some kind of "real proof", you can try using the [Vulcan Logic Disassembler](http://derickrethans.nl/vld.php), that will give you the opcodes corresponding to a PHP script.

---

**EDIT after the comment**

I've uploaded the outputs of using VLD with both syntaxes :
 - [vld-construct-new.txt](http://extern.pascal-martin.fr/so/vld-construct-new.txt) : when declaring __construct, and calling __construct.
 - [vld-construct-old.txt](http://extern.pascal-martin.fr/so/vld-construct-old.txt) : when declaring Foo, and calling __construct.

Doing a diff between the two files, this is what I get :

```
$ diff vld-construct-old.txt vld-construct-new.txt
25c25
< Function foo:
---
> Function __construct:
29c29
< function name:  Foo
---
> function name:  __construct
44c44
< End of function foo.
---
> End of function __construct.
71c71
< Function foo:
---
> Function __construct:
75c75
< function name:  Foo
---
> function name:  __construct
90c90
< End of function foo.
---
> End of function __construct.
```

*(Unified diff is much longer, so I'll stick to using the default format of "diff" here)*

So, the only differences in the disassembled opcodes are the names of the functions ; both in the `Foo` class and in the `Bar` class (that inherits the `__construct` / `Foo` method of class `Foo`).

What I would really say is :

- If you are writting PHP 5 code *(and, in 2009, I sincerely hope you do ^^ )*, then, just use the __construct syntax
- You you have to maintain some old PHP 4 code you can't migrate to PHP 5 *(you should)*, then, use the Foo syntax...

As the sidenote, [the documentation says](http://php.net/__construct) *(quoting)* :

> For backwards compatibility, if PHP 5
>   cannot find a `__construct()` function
>   for a given class, it will search for
>   the old-style constructor function, by
>   the name of the class.
>
> Effectively, it means that the only
>   case that would have compatibility
>   issues is if the class had a method
>   named `__construct()` which was used
>   for different semantics.

So, I really think there is not that much of a difference **:-)**

Did you encounter some kind of strange problem, that you think is caused by something like a difference between the two syntaxes ?

Comment: +1 From a code path point of view everything appears to work as intended.  What I'm not 100% clear on is if there's any special context/scoping that goes on when you call into a constructor that might be missing when you use the older constructor naming convention

Answer (score 1):

As of PHP 5.3.3 the old style ctor will not work when you are using namespaces.

See http://www.php.net/archive/2010.php#id2010-07-22-2