# Working on a registration controller with CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying my new hand at Code Igniter and have this issue come up.

( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Controller' not found in C:\wamp\www\kowmanager\system\application\controllers\user.php on line 2
Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

1   0.0007  695640  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0021  782824  require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\kowmanager\system\core\CodeIgniter.php' )    ..\index.php:201
3   0.0181  1938352 include( 'C:\wamp\www\kowmanager\system\application\controllers\user.php' ) ..\CodeIgniter.php:248

```
<?php
class User extends Controller {

function User() 
{
    parent :: Controller();
    $this->view_data['base_url'] = base_url();
}

function index()
{
    $this->register();
}

function register()
{
    $this->load->view('view_register', $this->view_data);
}

}
?>
```

EDIT:

I changed the class User extends CI_Controller but now I'm getting this:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Controller::Controller() in C:\wamp\www\kowmanager\system\application\controllers\user.php on line 6

Edit 2:

Here is my new code. Im getting Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Controller::User() in C:\wamp\www\kowmanager\system\application\controllers\user.php on line 6

```
<?php
class User extends CI_Controller {

function User() 
{
    parent :: User();
    $this->view_data['base_url'] = base_url();
}

function index()
{
    $this->register();
}

function register()
{
    $this->load->view('view_register', $this->view_data);
}

}
?>
```

Comment: Ver 2.0.1 onward, the constructor function is __construct() . I edited my answer. that should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this link. [Codeigniter constructors. What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357136/codeigniter-constructors-what-is-the-difference)

It seems you are using CodeIgniter 2+ and PHP 5. With which the old constructor method no longer works.

Ah, since I think you are using PHP 5.

```
function User() 
{
    parent :: User();
    $this->view_data['base_url'] = base_url();
}
```

You should use __construct() instead.

```
function User() 
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->view_data['base_url'] = base_url();
}
```

Or replace the function name also so it's much readable as overriding the parent constructor method.

```
function __construct() 
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->view_data['base_url'] = base_url();
}
```

Comment: Red the comment I left for Danae.

Answer (score 1):

The userguide uses this line:

`class User extends CI_Controller {`

Don't have quick access to my CI files at the moment, but I'd go with what the [userguide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html) says.

Comment: That doesn't help either. For some reason I copied the exact code from this video to get used to the framework and still is doing the same thing.

Comment: Could you confirm which video you used?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/user/Verbloten#p/u/42/bGCJNfE0szs sorry thought I included it but I also updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code for the constructor

```
function __construct() 
{
    parent ::__construct();
    $this->view_data['base_url'] = base_url();
}
```

instead of your function user()

Also,

```
class User extends CI_Controller
```

Comment: Okay, edited. The constructor has to be __construct in the new version.

Comment: Also, tank auth might be a much better way to go.

Comment: Do I need to do this with models as well?

Comment: When I change class User extends CI_Controller {
 
    function User()  to class User extends CI_Controller {
 
    function __constructor() then I get a A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: User::$view_data

Filename: controllers/user.php

Line Number: 29
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: base_url

Filename: views/view_register.php

Line Number: 13
 errors

Comment: @looneydoodle let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2382/discussion-between-jeff-davidson-and-looneydoodle)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I should have taken out the $baseUrl variable for my form open tag.