# The Path and Class Name is Correct, But Failed To Use Inherited PHP Class

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm using FPDF and WriteHTML Scripts (http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script42.php) to convert my HTML into PDF.

I've downloaded the FPDF library on my `/lib/fpdf` folder along with `WriteHTML` script.

so what inside `/lib/fpdf` folder is :

```
/lib/fpdf/fpdf.php
/lib/fpdf/html2pdf.php
```

then I write this code :

```
require_once ('html2pdf.php');
$html_code = ''; // some HTML code here

$pdf = new PDF_HTML();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->WriteHTML($html_code);
$pdf->Output();
```

this simple code gives me this error :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDF_HTML::FPDF() in /home/***/html2pdf.php on line 52
```

and here's what line 52 really is :

```
$this->FPDF($orientation,$unit,$format);
```

Why I got that error message while I'm following the tutorial correctly. Why the html2pdf script failed to recognize the method? thank you

Comment: Is `PDF_HTML` your own class, and if so, how is it defined?

Comment: no, bro. PDF_HTML is not my class. here's the source code : http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script42.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply rename the function `PDF_HTML` in `html2pdf.php` to `__construct` (to make it a *new style* PHP constructor) and replace `$this->FPDF` by `parent::__construct` (to call the right function):

```
// THIS: 
function PDF_HTML($orientation='P', $unit='mm', $format='A4')
{
    //Call parent constructor
    $this->FPDF($orientation,$unit,$format);

// BECOMES THAT:
function __construct($orientation='P', $unit='mm', $format='A4')
{
    //Call parent constructor
    parent::__construct($orientation,$unit,$format);
```

#### Explanation:

The problem is that the latest version of `fpdf.php` (1.8) uses new style constructor (`__construct`) while `PDF_HTML` in `script42.php` has not been updated to uses new style constructors (old style constructor is `ClassName`).

Since `PDF_HTML` inherit from `FPDF`, `$this->FPDF` should be call to a parent constructor (see [Calling PHP Parent Constructors With Old/New Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223766/calling-php-parent-constructors-with-old-new-syntax)), which would work if `FPDF` was using old-style constructor:

```
class FPDF {
    // Constructor (in PHP < 5.3.3), Deprecated in PHP 7+
    public function FPDF () {

    }
}

class PDF_HTML {
    // Constructor (in PHP < 5.3.3)
    public function PDF_HTML () {
        $this->FPDF(); // Call to parent constructor
    }
}
```

You clearly see in [`script42.php`](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script42.php) that `PDF_HTML` uses the old style constructor:

```
function PDF_HTML($orientation='P', $unit='mm', $format='A4')
```

Unfortunately, `FPDF` 1.8 uses new style constructor:

```
class FPDF {
    public function __construct () { }
}
```

So you cannot call a parent constructor defined with the new style using the old style.

---

*Note:* If you really want to use the code of `script42.php` as it is now, you should try to find an old version of `fpdf.php` (FPDF 1.7 uses old style constructors) and use a PHP version `< 7` because old style constructor are deprecated in `PHP 7+` (and are [considered standard function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) in `PHP 5.3.3+`).

Comment: you make this problem looks pretty clear with your clear explanation, bro. thank you very much and I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all. You try to call a method that simply does not exist. I looked at the source of `PDF_HTML` class and there really is no such method.

Methods available are (+ methods defined by FPDF class):

- `PDF_HTML()` The construciotr of that class
- `WriteHTML()`
- `OpenTag()`
- `CloseTag()`
- `SetStyle()`
- `PutLink()`

Looks like you either instantiate the wrong class or call the wrong function.

Comment: I thing there's something wrong with this class : http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script42.php.

it has `PDF_HTML` as a class name and it also has `PDF_HTML` as method's name.

once I changed the class name into `PDF2HTML`, there's no error message anymore.

I'm still new in PHP OOP, but is it illegal to use class name as method's name?